# html video background, best cross browser/mobile solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to get a video background on one of my web pages.
I've tried converting my video to several formats(ogg,mp4..etc) and testing a few plugins, however I cant seem to get video backgrounds to play on mobiles and some older browsers (firefox, IE7).

Does anyone know what the best way to do this would be to date?

Comment: Most mobile devices don't allow video autoplay

Comment: what about modern ones like iphones, i've seen some websites which could do this before

Comment: Ok sorry, IIRC, depending on network connection (wifi, 3g, etc...), autoplay video can be unable/disable on modern iphone. But i guess this is regarding specific user config too. BTW, i don't have an iphone so don't take it seriously